# Python3x: How do I get coordinates for addresses from the csv list?

Tags: python-3.x, geopy, nominatim

I have a list with addresses in the csv file. I would like to get coordinates for this whole list. Unfortunately, I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-375-e8f87c93126d>", line 8, in <module>
        print(location.address)

    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'
```

I do not know what is wrong. When I enter instead of and a specific address from my list, the loop works correctly.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

for i in adres:
    geolocator = Nominatim()
    location = geolocator.geocode(i)
    time.sleep(.45)
    print(location.address)
    print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

These are the first records from my 'adres' list:

```
    print (adres)
['Ul. Sądowa 8  74-320 Barlinek            ', 'Ul. Armii Polskiej 36  73-260 Pełczyce            ', 'Ul. H. Sienkiewicza 5  66-500 Strzelce Krajeńskie            '
```

Comment: `geocode()` returns `None` when there are no results. What does your `adres` look like? Can you check with using `print(adres)` right before that loop?

Comment: I added the result print (adres) of the first three records.

Comment: There are lots of spaces in those. Try using strip method to remove extra whitespace.

Comment: ['Ul. Sądowa 8 74-320 Barlinek', 'Ul. Armii Polskiej 36 73-260 Pełczyce'

Comment: I removed the spaces. The same error all the time.